# Installed caret but still missing createDataPartition function in R

Tags: r

I am new to R so I tried predicting using linear reg model and I am getting the error as shown in the image below, can you help me out?

Libraries included:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(tidypredict)
```

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZWwa.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to avoid pictures. Moreover try to demonstrate your problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `library(caret)` again, if the package is loaded, `createDataPartition` is there. If you still face the issue, check for `Caret` updates.

Comment: I downloaded R tools and somehow it worked idk why tho!